# How to take out list of objects through angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my controller code:

```
var domainList=angular.copy($scope.busdomain);
            if(domainList!=null){
                 domainList[0].childNode.sort();
//For finding out the length of list
                for (var i = 0; i < domainList[0].childNode.length; i++) {
//Here I want to add a check that I can get name only of objects in my list
//Please see the attached Object screenshot for better understanding
                    if (domainList[0].childNode[i].name!=null) {
                        var name=domainList[0].childNode[i].name;
                     domainList[0].childNode.splice(i,1,name);
                      $scope.busdomainname=domainList[0].childNode;
}
}
```

I want to get the list of object and take out its name and add to $scope.busdomainname as I need to display only name on another page.
Is there any way to do this. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try underscore library [example](http://code.runnable.com/UlqCH0ATImsoAAER/how-to-pluck-values-from-array-with-underscore-js-for-jquery-and-javascript) instead of going the hard way. It provides useful functions like this. Your case

```
_.pluck (domainList, "name");
```

Comment: Could you add an example?